# Exporting stash/bitbucket data as XML or JSON

Tags: bitbucket

Is there any convenient way to export data from stash/bitbucket as XML or JSON from within the Java API?  I'm specifically looking at pull requests and would like to stream them on stdout for processing by an external script.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you need, but there are a few options.

### Bitbucket REST API

From java you can easily use the Stash/Bitbucket REST API to retrieve information. This typically outputs json.

For example, you can use this resource to search for pull requests:

```
/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests
```

It returns output like:

```
{
"size": 1,
"limit": 25,
"isLastPage": true,
"values": [
    {
        "id": 101,
        "version": 1,
        "title": "Talking Nerdy",
        "description": "It’s a kludge, but put the tuple from the database in the cache.",
        "state": "OPEN",
        "open": true,
        "closed": false,
        "createdDate": 1359075920,
        "updatedDate": 1359085920,
        "fromRef": {
            "id": "refs/heads/feature-ABC-123",
            "repository": {
                "slug": "my-repo",
                "name": null,
                "project": {
                    "key": "PRJ"
                }
            }
        },
        "toRef": {
            "id": "refs/heads/master",
            "repository": {
                "slug": "my-repo",
                "name": null,
                "project": {
                    "key": "PRJ"
                }
            }
        },
        "locked": false,
        "author": {
            "user": {
                "name": "tom",
                "emailAddress": "tom@example.com",
                "id": 115026,
                "displayName": "Tom",
                "active": true,
                "slug": "tom",
                "type": "NORMAL"
            },
            "role": "AUTHOR",
            "approved": true,
            "status": "APPROVED"
        },
        "reviewers": [
            {
                "user": {
                    "name": "jcitizen",
                    "emailAddress": "jane@example.com",
                    "id": 101,
                    "displayName": "Jane Citizen",
                    "active": true,
                    "slug": "jcitizen",
                    "type": "NORMAL"
                },
                "role": "REVIEWER",
                "approved": true,
                "status": "APPROVED"
            }
        ],
        "participants": [
            {
                "user": {
                    "name": "dick",
                    "emailAddress": "dick@example.com",
                    "id": 3083181,
                    "displayName": "Dick",
                    "active": true,
                    "slug": "dick",
                    "type": "NORMAL"
                },
                "role": "PARTICIPANT",
                "approved": false,
                "status": "UNAPPROVED"
            },
            {
                "user": {
                    "name": "harry",
                    "emailAddress": "harry@example.com",
                    "id": 99049120,
                    "displayName": "Harry",
                    "active": true,
                    "slug": "harry",
                    "type": "NORMAL"
                },
                "role": "PARTICIPANT",
                "approved": true,
                "status": "APPROVED"
            }
        ],
        "links": {
            "self": [
                {
                    "href": "http://link/to/pullrequest"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
],
"start": 0
}
```

For info about available parameters and other resources, see [the documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/4.5.1/bitbucket-rest.html#idp2619568).

### Script Runner for Bitbucket

If you run Bitbucket Server, you could also look at the '[Script runner for Bitbucket](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.stash.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview)' add-on. It provides a lot of functionality to customise your Bitbucket using Groovy scripts and it comes with a number of scripts out of the box. You can also easily add scripts to respond to events like "pull request created". More info in its [documentation](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/bitbucket/StashEventHandlers.html).

You can also execute REST calls from within your Groovy scripts.

Groovy is very flexible in how it handle json, so if you want complete control over what json is generated, you can check [JsonSlurper and JsonOutput](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html).

### Custom java

If you have a standalone java application and you want complete control over what json/xml is returned, you can do all of that using libraries like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), JAXB and/or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Hope this helps.